# Что такое рекрусивные алгоритмы и переполнение стека при их использовании?

Tags: алгоритм, рекурсия, стек, переполнение

Что такое рекрусивные алгоритмы? Какие бывают их виды? Как избежать переполнения стека при рекурсивном вызове?

Comment: Вопрос нечетко поставлен. Например "Что такое коса?". Что за "рекурсия"? Рекурсивные алгоритмы? Языковая синтаксическая рекурсия? Это совершенно разные вещи. И какое именно переполнение имеется в виду?

Comment: @AnT в таких случаях надо сообщать автору об уточнении и тд., а не сразу же закрывать вопрос. ИМХО

Comment: @Lex Hobbit: У меня нет привилегий "сразу же закрывать вопрос". Закрытие вопроса тут делается через голосование, причем именно с сообщением автору.

Comment: Эм.. А эти два вопроса как-то связаны?

Comment: @AnT я не имел ввиду конкретно вас. Я не понимаю в данном случае, почему люди минусуют вопрос.

Comment: О, теперь лучше)

Comment: Нет не лучше, а хуже. Понятие "рекурсивные алгоритмы" говорит об *алгоритмах*. В алгоритмах не бывает никакого "переполнения стека" как нет и никакого "стека" (если его специально не создал автор алгоритма). Алгоритмическая рекурсия и рекурсия в процедурных ЯП - два разных мира. "Переполнение стека" - тема из области практических ЯП. "Рекурсивные алгоритмы" - тема из теории computer science. О чем именно вопрос?

Comment: @Александр: Вы посылаете человека в Гугл, Гугл приводит его на StackOverflow, где человека снова посылают в Гугл и т. д. Это как раз хороший пример рекурсии.

Answer (score 3):

Если очень кратко, рекурсия - вызов из функции самой себя.

Например, что такое факториал? `n! = n* (n-1) *(n-2) * ... * 1 = n * (n-1)!`

Так что можно написать рекурсивную функцию вычисления факториала (набросаю на C):

```
int factorial(int n)
{  
    if (n == 1) return 1;      // Окончание рекурсии
    return n * factorial(n-1); // Рекурсивный вызов самой себя
}
```

Ну, а поскольку каждый вызов функции требует память в стеке - для аргументов, локальных переменных и так далее - то очень много таких вызовов могут занять под себя весь стек - **переполнить** его. Это - переполнение в контексте рекурсии.

Но может быть и переполнение в контексте типов данных - например, для целого числа выделено 4 байта, но число пытаемся сохранить такое, которое туда не помещается...

Comment: Уточню что функция не обязательно должна вызывать сама себя напрямую. например funA вызывает funB которая вызывает funA тоже является рекурсией.

Comment: @ИльяЧижанов Спасибо за дополнение.

Comment: @Harry добавьте, пожалуйста, еще способы избежать переполнения. Например, динамическое программирование и тд.

Comment: @LexHobbit Давайте это сделаете вы в своем ответе. Просто я как-то не очень представляю, что динамическое программирование - это способ избежать переполнения при рекурсии...

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу @Harry.

### Виды рекурсии

Рекурсивные функции можно выделить несколько видов:

- ***линейная рекурсия***, при которой рекурсивные вызовы на любом рекурсивном срезе, инициируют не более одного последующего рекурсивного вызова.(как в примере у @Harry)
- ***хвостовая рекурсия*** (частный случай линейной рекурсии), при которой рекурсивный вызов функции происходит в конце её работы. (как в примере у @Harry).
- ***нелинейная или параллельная рекурсия***,  при которой рекурсивные вызовы на любом рекурсивном срезе, инициируют более одного последующего рекурсивного вызова.

Хороший пример данного вида - это вычисление `n-го` члена ряда Фибоначчи:

```
int fib(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) { return 0; } // Окончание рекурсии
    else
    {
        if ((n == -1) || (n == 1)) { return 1; } // Окончание рекурсии
        else 
        {
            if (n > 0) { return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2); }// параллельный рекурсивный вызов самой себя
            else { return fib(n + 2) - fib(n + 1); } // параллельный рекурсивный вызов самой себя
        }
    }
}
```

- ***взаимная или косвенная рекурсия***, при которой рекурсивный вызов данной функции происходит из какой-либо другой функции, которая сама вызывалась из данной функции.

Пример вычисления(искусственный):

```
int factorial_odd(int x)
{
   if(x == 0)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   return factorial_even(x – 1);
}

int factorial_even(int x)
{
   if(x == 0)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   return factorial_odd(x – 1);
}

int factorial (int x)
{
    if(x % 2 == 0)
    {
        return factorial_even(x);
    }
    else
    {
        return factorial_odd(x);
    }
}
```

### Когда стоит использовать рекурсию?

Пользуйтесь рекурсией, если:

1. задача разбивается на уменьшенные копии самой себя, и нет очевидного способа решить ее написанием цикла;
2. вы работаете с рекурсивной структурой данных, например со связанными списками

***НО:*** Если задачу можно решить итеративно, то пользуйтесь итерацией.

### Как избежать переполнения при рекурсии?

1. Обязательно должно присутствовать условие выхода из рекурсии.
2. Если правило 1 удовлетворено, но все равно происходит переполнение, то стоит отказаться от использования рекурсии и реализовать алгоритм итеративно. (циклы и динамическое программирование вам в помощь)

Пример итеративного вычисления факториала:

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    int sum = 1;
    if (n <= 1) return sum;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        sum *= n;
        n--;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Напоследок, лучшее понимание теории достигается путем ее применения на [практике](https://habrahabr.ru/post/275813/).