# Как переделать обычную рекурсию в хвостовую?

Tags: java, рекурсия

При таком коде у меня получается `stackoverflow` (простите за каламбур):

```
public double calculate(long n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 0;
    else return f.apply((double) n) + calculate(n);
}
```

Можно ли эту рекурсию переделать в хвостовую для избежания ошибки ?

*Класс целиком:*

```
public class MyFunction {

    private String title;
    private Function<Double, Double> f;


    public MyFunction(String title, Function<Double, Double> f) {
        this.title = title;
        this.f = f;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Function<Double, Double> getFunction() {
        return f;
    }

    public double calculate(long n) {
        if (n <= 0) return 0;
        else return f.apply((double) n) + calculate(n);
    }

}
```

*Пример использования:*

```
long N = (long) pow(10, 1000);
MyFunction f1 = new MyFunction("test", x -> pow(x + 1, x + 0.1) / x);
System.out.println(f1.calculate(N));
```

Comment: Где задана переменная `f`, для чего она вообще нужна, и что вас действительно беспокоит: нерабочий код или хвостовая рекурсия?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: разве `java` умеет в хвостовую рекурсию?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В этом и вопрос. Можно ли это сделать и если да, то как.

Comment: @faoxis похоже zRrr уже написал что надо сделать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а разве `return (n <= 0) ? 0 : calculate(n - 1);` - это не хвостовая рекурсия?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, то хвостовая рекурсия выглядела бы так: `return n <= 0 ? acc : calculate(n, acc + f.apply((double) n));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете свой рекурсивыный алгоритм преобразовать в итеративный, что не будет приводить к переполнению стека. Можете почитать в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/692730/199793). Рекурсия из вашего примера в итеративном виде:

```
public double calculate(long n)
{
    double sum = 0;
    if (n <= 0) return sum;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        sum += f.apply((double) n);
        n--;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

## UPD#1

Что касается непосредственно вашего вопроса, то в комментариях вы сами же дали правильный ответ. Хвостовая рекурсия будет выглядеть так:

```
public double calculate(long n)
{
    return calculate(n, 0);
}


public double calculate(long n, double sum)
{
    return n <= 0 ? sum: calculate(n - 1, sum + f.apply((double) n));
}
```

Обернул в переопределенный метод, чтобы не менять код, где используется метод с одним параметром. Таким образом, когда программа входит в ветку `else`(тернанрного оператора) снова и снова, нам больше не нужен фактический стек - у программы есть все, что ей нужно, в качестве аргументов метода в рекурсивном вызове.

## UPD#2

Действительно, как показала практика, в Java 1.8 нет оптимизации хвостовой рекурсии (TRO). В ходе исполнения кода все равно наращивается стек. Думал может быть можно решить этот вопрос с использованием `lambda`-функций, но не удалось и с этого момента мы все погружаемся в <strike>мир магии</strike> шаблонные функции  =) Воспользуемся ***трамплином*** <strike>для прыжков</strike> шаблоном проектирования, который преобразует стеково зависимую рекурсию в соответствующий итеративный алгоритм. Поскольку циклы не вызывают стекового спуска, это можно рассматривать как форму бесстековой рекурсии. Вот код для проверки:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;


class Trampoline<T>
{
    public T getValue() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
    }

    public Optional<Trampoline<T>> nextTrampoline() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    public final T compute() {
        Trampoline<T> trampoline = this;

        while (trampoline.nextTrampoline().isPresent()) {
            trampoline = trampoline.nextTrampoline().get();
        }

        return trampoline.getValue();
    }
}

final class StacklessRecursiveFunction
{
    public static Trampoline<Double> createTrampoline(final double n, final double sum)
    {
        if (n <= 0) {
            return new Trampoline<Double>() {
                public Double getValue() { return sum; }
            };
        }

        return new Trampoline<Double>() {
            public Optional<Trampoline<Double>> nextTrampoline() {
                return Optional.of(createTrampoline(n - 1, sum + Math.pow(n + 1, n + 0.1) / n));
            }
        };
    }
}

class MagicStacklessRecur{

public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(StacklessRecursiveFunction.createTrampoline(Math.pow(10,1000), 0).compute());
    }
}
```

Comment: У меня при хвостовой рекурсии все равно возникает `stackoverflow`. Значит ли это, что `Java` не умеет избегать наращивание стека при ней ?

Comment: @faoxis момент, сейчас сделаю upd#2 с проверочкой =)

Comment: @faoxis про это не так давно была [статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/319282/).

Comment: @faoxis добавил upd#2